# Java nio FileChannel write method clarfication

Tags: java

I have following code to write by file channel

```
fc.write(bytebuffer, position);
```

In several tutorials i referred this is ok and it does the job fine. But in the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer-long- this method returns no of bytes written. Therefore my question is, is it possible in some case this will write only part of bytebuffer ? Do i need to wrap this inside a loop ? Is this code has bug waiting to happen ?

Answer (score 1):

The method `FileChannel.write(...)` implements the method `WritableByteChannel.write(...)`. This interface can be used for many kinds of channels. The `WritableByteChannel.write(...)` documentation tells:

> Unless otherwise specified, a write operation will return only after
> writing all of the r requested bytes. Some types of channels,
> depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes or
> possibly none at all. A socket channel in non-blocking mode, for
> example, cannot write any more bytes than are free in the socket's
> output buffer.

But in your case with a `FileChannel` it will always write and returns the remaining element in your `ByteBuffer`.